# Simple Tutorial, camel spring routing, activemq, xslt

Tags: xml, spring, xslt, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I am trying to find out if anyone knows of a simple tutorial that does something like the following steps:

1. Send xml message to activemq topic
2. Transform message in topic with xslt
3. Send transformed message to second topic
4. log out contents of transformed xml message

I am trying to do the following using camel spring based routing. Any help would be greatly appreciated with this. I currently have a program that sends a simple String to an activemq topic, logs out the contents of the string, and then passes the String to a second topic. So basically I just want to change sending a simple text message to an xml message that is transformed along the way.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to Romins answer, specifically transforming the message with XSLT is trivial and described in detail in the [camel xslt docs](http://camel.apache.org/xslt).

You seem to have done the other parts.

Comment: Thank you very much, I took a look at those docs and I am pretty sure that I have the xsl's created correctly to transform my input xml to the route. My only issue now is I am having trouble figuring out what the best way to actually send an xml payload to my activemq topic actually is. I thought about just passing the entire thing as a string, but I am not sure if my xsl will pick it up at that point then. Any tips?

Comment: Just pass as string is the far most easy and common way to do it. What other option were you considering?

Comment: I really wasn't sure honestly. I just didn't know if there was a better option out there. So something like... Session session = connection.createSession(); TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage() message.setText("<TestEntry><Test></Test></TestEntry>") ?

Comment: My only question is regarding the xml version and encoding tags, I am getting a "UTF cannot be resolved to a variable error" I am not sure if this is just something I have wrong with my opening and terminating quotes or if I shouldn't include it with the message.

Comment: Sure, or something more sophisticated with namespaces and XML declaration, but yes. Just pass the message as a string like that.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` could certainly be included at the beginning. I assume you have some syntax errors somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a list of resources and you should be able to find your way to the article that helps you out in what you want to do.

- [StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406656/is-there-any-simple-tutorial-or-a-source-to-learn-apache-camel)
- [Tutorials hosted at Apache Camel Site](http://camel.apache.org/tutorials.html)
- [Article list](http://camel.apache.org/articles.html)